# "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to boolean"

Tags: java, opencv

I'm currently trying to run the code below, but I keep getting the error message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to boolean". This is particularly confusing to me since: 1) I'm not sure where I'm attempting to make such a conversion, and 2) the code runs perfectly with Eclipse on other computers I've used.

Could anyone point out what the problem might be here? I'm pretty baffled. By the way, the errors come from these lines:

`SizeCustom = false;`

`SizeCustom = true;`

`if (SizeCustom) {`

in the full code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

//import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
//import java.io.InputStream;
//import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
//import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Imshow {

public JFrame Window;
private ImageIcon image;
private JLabel label;
// private MatOfByte matOfByte;
private Boolean SizeCustom;
private int Height, Width;

public Imshow(String title) {
    Window = new JFrame();
    image = new ImageIcon();
    label = new JLabel();
    // matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    label.setIcon(image);
    Window.getContentPane().add(label);
    Window.setResizable(false);
    Window.setTitle(title);
    SizeCustom = false;
    setCloseOption(0);
}

public Imshow(String title, int height, int width) {
    SizeCustom = true;
    Height = height;
    Width = width;

    Window = new JFrame();
    image = new ImageIcon();
    label = new JLabel();
    // matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    label.setIcon(image);
    Window.getContentPane().add(label);
    Window.setResizable(false);
    Window.setTitle(title);
    setCloseOption(0);

}

public void showImage(Mat img) {
    if (SizeCustom) {
        Imgproc.resize(img, img, new Size(Height, Width));
    }
    // Highgui.imencode(".jpg", img, matOfByte);
    // byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;
    try {
        // InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        // bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        bufImage = toBufferedImage(img);
        image.setImage(bufImage);
        Window.pack();
        label.updateUI();
        Window.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It gets set to `false` in the constructor. Would that make it non-null?

Comment: which line is giving you that error?

Comment: `if (SizeCustom)` -- here is your conversion (unboxing) from Boolean to boolean. it's really strange, but try using `if (SizeCustom.booleanValue())` instead

Comment: Sorry, just edited to display the lines causing the error.

Comment: off topic but variable names should be lower case (except static finals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Boolean' and 'boolean' are actual different.  'Boolean' is a class, whereas 'boolean' is a primitive.  You have an if statement checking on the 'boolean' value of SizeCustom, but SizeCustom is 'Boolean'.  You can do one of two things:

1) Change SizeCustom to a 'boolean' type.

2) Use the 'booleanValue()' method on the 'Boolean' typed SizeCustom to get your 'boolean' value for your if statment.

Comment: Autoboxing should take care of it though.  Might be worth checking the Eclipse project settings for JDK compliance level - make sure it is >= 1.5.

Comment: Solved it with 1). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're using `private Boolean SizeCustom` over `private boolean SizeCustom`? If there's not, it's better to change it to `boolean`. The difference between a Boolean and a boolean is that Boolean is a class and boolean a primitive.

The reason it worked before is that you probably used a newer version of the JDK on other PC's. Autoboxing (Boolean to boolean and vice versa) was introduced in JDK 1.5 (Java 5). If you're using an older one, that's why it's not working.